# Adding subclass to Storyboard crashes

Tags: ios, swift

This is my class of a UIView:

```
class overlap: UIView{
    init() {
        super.init(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

It should just fill up the screen. When I add the view in Storyboard with constraints pinned to the edges of the screen, it crashes when I launch the app. The error comes up as stated in the code above.

Creating and adding the subclass programmatically works with this init function:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
}
```

But I want it reusable through Storyboard, without adding code. What is wrong with my code, and is it even possible what I want?

Thanks!

Comment: `fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")` – guess what gets called when instantiating a storyboard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> it crashes when I launch the app

Because that is what your code *told* it to do.

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

`fatalError` means "crash me".